# redirect after 30s if has been checked the checkbox javascript

Tags: javascript

i am new with java script how can i make it, if is checked from user to redirect after 30s, i tried with some javascript from others website but didn't help

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="redirect30sid" name="redirect30sname" value="Redirectvalue">Redirect me after 30s<br>
```

Comment: What JavaScript did you try?

Comment: There's no javascript in your code yet. Please check [Location.href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) and see what it can do for you :)

Comment: that is the point i don't know very well java script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="handleClick(this)">Redirect me after 30s<br>
<script>
  let handleClick = (ele) => {
    if (ele.checked) {
      redirectTime = setTimeout(() => {
        window.location = "/"
      }, 30000)
    } else if (!ele.checked && typeof redirectTime !== 'undefined') {
      clearTimeout(redirectTime);
    }
  }

</script>
```

much cleaner, simpler.

edit: if the checkbox is unchecked within 30s redirect doesn't fire.

Comment: wonderful, well done with unchecked within 30s redirect doesn't fire this made my day

Answer (score 1):

By selecting the checkbox and adding an event listener on it that activates on changing the state of the checkbox.

```
var checkbox = document.querySelector("#redirect30sid");

checkbox.addEventListener( 'change', function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        // Checkbox is checked..
         setTimeout(function(){
             window.location.href = "https://www.example.com";//put your url here
             }, 30000);//Time in ms

    } else {
        // Checkbox is not checked..
        //Do other stuff
    }
})
```

Comment: The actual event to occur after the timeout is to be put in a function as the first argument to setTimeout. The redirect here will happen immediately.

Comment: @Shushan I edited the post is that what you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="redirect30sid" name="redirect30sname" value="Redirectvalue">Redirect me after 30s

<script>
  const checkboxElement = document.getElementById('redirect30sid')
  checkboxElement.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        // Double check if the check box is still checked
        if (event.target.checked)
            window.location = checkboxElement.value;
      }, 30 * 1000);
    }
  })
</script>
```

Pure Javascript

Comment: While this achieves the goal, one should note that in case a user removes the 'check' from the checkbox, he will still be redirected as we did not withdraw the timeout.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Another solution is to double check the value before redirect.